# Method to send multiple paperclip attachments through actionmailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, actionmailer, cocoon-gem

So I need my mailer to send attachments that the user uploads in the form upon creation.  I used cocoon and paperclip to attach multiple files in the form.

Here is my object_controller:

```
class RfqsController < ApplicationController
...

  def create
    @object= Rfq.new(rfq_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @object.save
        Object_mailer.object_message(current_user, @object).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @object, notice: 'object was successfully created.' }

        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will send the email with multiple attachments

```
class ObjectMailer < ApplicationMailer

  default from: "test@test.com"
  def placeholder_message(user, rfq)
    @user = user

    object.object_attachments.each do |attachment|
      attachments[attachment.attachment_file_file_name] = File.read(attachment.attachment_file.path)
    end

    mail to: user.email, subject: "test" 
  end

end
```